# How to get Owl carousel current item in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

How I get the current item selected in react-owl-carousel.
I did use to get the id during translated event and also tried all events in official document.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-owl-carousel
BTW: how is possible to get the info: parmater(just like in Jquery) I am not able to get any response from this.

```
return <div className="rp-slider-main owl-carousel clearfix">
      <OwlCarousel className="owl-theme" loop={false} nav={false} autoWidth={false} items={1} center={false}  onChanged={() => handleSelect(e)}>
        {props.commentsArr.map((topComment, index) => (
            <div className=item key={index}>
        ..........
    </div>
     )}
     </OwlCarousel>
   </div>
```

And my event is

```
handleSelect(e) {var index = e.page.index;}
```

here index does not change when user changes the slide item
How do I get the current slide item id or least the slide #number,and want to make sure that I have selected the right event'onTranslated'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use onChanged event of it, it will give you current index

```
<OwlCarousel className="owl-theme" loop={true} nav={false} autoWidth={false} items={1} center={false} onChanged={() => props.handleSelect(e)} >
```

Comment: Did as onChanged. But my slider does not work. It keeps the first item active all the time. When I remove it, the slider works perfectly. And my And console.log(e.page); shows as {index: 1, count: 3, size: 1} {index: -1, count: 0, size: 1} {index: -1, count: 0, size: 1} {index: -1, count: 0, size: 1} {index: -1, count: 0, size: 1} What am I missing here.. Is there such any examples.

Comment: I do notice that its trigger the event twice. That might be the cause. Why is it so. I have modified the question with more info